# Add Delete button extjs grid

Tags: css, extjs, icons, gridpanel

I have a grid panel wherein I wish to add a delete button for every row. When a user clicks the button that row is deleted. Also I wanted to have a save button at the bottom which helps the user add a row to the grid. The issue is that I am adding the rows dynamically. So for each row the delete icon should also be added like that.

My requirements are just for 2 columns. One displays the name and the other will display the icon for delete.

Kindly advise me how to go about adding the icon to each row dynamically. I have a CSS already in place which goes something like this:

```
.icon-delete {
    background-image: url(../images/delete.png) !important;
}
```

This CSS is in a different file. I am new to extjs so I don't really have much experience with such features.

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following but it doesn't display the icon. Please tell me where am I wrong.

```
columns : [{
    text : 'Name', 
    dataIndex : 'name', 
    width : '50%'
},
{
    xtype : 'actioncolumn',
    draggable : false,
    hideable : false,
    menuDisabled : true,
    width:'50%',
    items : [{
        iconCls: 'icon-delete',
        tooltip: 'Delete',
        scope: this,                   
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Ext.grid.column.Action` class, like this :

```
{
    xtype:'actioncolumn',
    width:20,
    items: [{
        iconCls: 'icon-delete',
        tooltip: 'Delete',
        handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
            grid.getStore().removeAt(rowIndex);
        },
        scope: this
    }]
}
```

Documentation for the class : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action

Comment: But when I add a row how do I add this column value ? Like I am doing Ext.getCmp('gridId').getStore().add({'name' : 'test}); for adding a row. How do I add the icon to this row as well? Also, the 'icon' field according to my css should be 'icon-delete' right?

Comment: The concept of `actioncolumn` is that it adds the button(s) to each row in the store next to the data. As for the CSS, my bad, i'll edit my post as I forgot to adapt it to your CSS

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am now clear about the concept of 'actioncolumn'. But the icon is still not displayed. Can you please have a look at the updated post?

Comment: I think you need to put a path to an image like I did before in the `icon` property. Maybe the `iconCls` is not enough. I'm not sure, since I always used images with no CSS

Comment: I tried that already but sadly that doesn't work either. Problem is that there is no error so I am unable to understand the problem cause.

Comment: Using your browser's developer tools, can you check that the button actually exists (even if the image isn't shown), and check that the CSS is applied properly ?